# SUMIF with month criterion

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have:

```
=SUMIF('Log'!A2:A139,MONTH('Log'!A2:A139)=1,'Log'!M2:M139)
```

Colums A in the 'Log' sheet contains dates. I want only to sum the values in the M column of the Log sheet IF the month is January.

The current expression keeps on returning `0`, am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second argument, the criteria has to relate back to each cell in the first argument. So, giving `MONTH()` a range isn't going to do any good there, it just keeps comparing A *x* to `MONTH(A2)` and getting a FALSE.

There are two easy solutions:

1. Create a scratch column, say `N`, with MONTH(A2), then use *that* column:

   ```
   =SUMIF('Log'!N2:N139,1,'Log'!M2:M139)
   ```
2. Use an Array formula:

   ```
   {=SUM('Log'!M2:M139 * IF(MONTH('Log'!A2:A139)=1,1,0))}
   ```

(Array formulas aren't entered with literal `{}` around them, they are entered using Shift-Enter and just appear with the `{}` around them in Excel.)

Comment: Also if you are using the complete column you can express the range like `A2:A`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not to hand when this Q was asked but [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) is now available and by accepting multiple conditions one (`>`) can be set as the end of December and one (`<`) as the start of February - thus selecting January without a helper column and no potentially slow array formula. This won't combine Januaries from different years (but could be set to do so).

Answer (score 0):

I landed here with same situation. But what you mean by create scratch column with MONTH(A2)?

> Create a scratch column, say N, with MONTH(A2), then use that column:
> =SUMIF('Log'!N2:N139,1,'Log'!M2:M139)

Comment: Please create your own question, do **not** post your [concerns](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21693/how-do-i-reference-another-question-and-is-it-ok-to-post-a-question-as-a-comment) as an answer to another question.